# Objective-C memory management: do I have to release what I alloc?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I'm a newbie Objective-C developer (for iPhone development) and I have a question about memory management. 
my code is just below;

```
Model1* model = [[Model1 alloc] init]; 
model.username = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"ysnky"]; 
[model.username release];  // is it needed
```

do I have to release model.username since I alloc?

**Model1.h**

```
@interface Model1 : NSObject {
    NSString* username;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* username;
@end
```

**Model1.m**

```
@implementation Model1
@synthesize username;

-(void) dealloc {
    [username release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code as you have written it, yes, you have to release that string because as you've noticed it's a string you `alloc/init`'ed and then the property causes an additional `retain`.

But you could also just do:

```
model.username = @"ysnky";
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all please use code tag to wrap your code.

do something like:

```
model.username = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"ysnky"];
```

is very discouraged you can use isntead:

model.username = @"ysnky"

in this case you don't have to worry about the object release.

But if you want to use

```
model.username = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"ysnky"];
```

the response to your question  is NO. You don't need to call

```
[model.username release]
```

or to be more precisous your code is wrong, you have to do something like:

```
Model1* model = [[Model1 alloc] init]; 
NSString *tmpString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"ysnky"] 
model.username = tmpString; 
[tmpString release];
```

finally I suggest to you to best design your class, you can make better by doing a initializer like:

```
Model1* model = [[Model1 alloc] initWithUsername:@"skdnaodnsa"];
```

Comment: Without [model.username release], the code as written would leak.

Comment: If you read one line below I explain why is not good call [model.username release]

Comment: hi guys i am still confused. YES or NO? i know model.username = @"ysnky" kind of usage but i just want to know the concept if i use alloc. since in my application it is not string object, is is a custom object.

Comment: If you keep your code as is YES you need to call release because after an alloc/init you retain count is 1, and when you assign the object to model.username your retain count go to 2 because you have declared the property as retain. But I strongly reccomend you to clean your code.

Comment: sorry for have made some mess...but i'd like to show you some best practice